# Get all NSArrays within an NSArray that contains a specific Key

Tags: casting, swift, nsarray

I have an NSArray that outputs the following:

```
(
    {
    category = 1;
    categoryname = Random;
    excuse = "Enter your excuse here";
    id = 1;
    name = Jo;
},
    {
    category = 2;
    categoryname = School;
    excuse = "Enter your excuse here";
    id = 2;
    name = Jo;
},
    {
    category = 2;
    categoryname = School;
    excuse = "Enter your excuse here";
    id = 3;
    name = if;
}
)
```

Now as you can see, there are different values for `category`. I am passing through an `Int` that I want to compare to that `category` value to only retrieve those objects within a certain category in another NSArray.

Here is my code to so:

```
func getAllExcusesData(categoryID: Int) -> NSMutableArray {
    var arr: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    for excuse in allExcusesData {
        println(excuse["category"]) // this line outputs "Optioanl(x)" - x is either 1 or 2, depending on what index I pass through
// it crashes here, at the 'if' line
        if excuse["category"] as Int == categoryID {
            var e: NSArray = excuse as NSArray
            arr.addObject(excuse)
        }
    }
    return arr
}
```

It crashes at the `if` line, it does however give the error:
`Thread 1:EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_1386_BPT, subcode=0x0)`

How can I compare the `category` field from the object to the given index and then add that one to the new array that will be returned from the method?

Answer (score 1):

The subscript returns an optional value of `AnyObject?` - you have to unwrap it before casting it or comparing to another value in one of the following ways:

```
if let excuseCategory: AnyObject = excuse["category"]? {
    if excuseCategory as Int == categoryID {
        // do sth
    }
}

// or if you're absolutely sure that "category" key always exists:

if excuse["category"]! as Int == categoryID {
    // do sth
}
```

---

Considering the fact that `Array` is bridged between `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray`, you can "swiftify" your code:

```
func getAllExcusesData(categoryID: Int) -> NSArray {
    return (allExcusesData as [AnyObject]).filter({ excuse in
        return excuse["category"]! as Int == categoryID
    })
}
```

Comment: Gives the exact same error, and it is at the `excuse["category"]! as Int` line. And I know that there is that key because I am able to print it out beforehand

Comment: excuse["category"] is probably a string then

Comment: That's what happens when you're trying to use `NSArray` in Swift.

Comment: Try `if excuse["category"]! as String == "\(categoryID)"`